# List two events with "both"

Tags: grammar, expressions

I am currently writing my cover letter for a PhD application and I want to list to events, one in the past and one currently happening with the word "both". I am trying to reconcile the following:

> "Both my BSc and MSc theses were (are) supervised by Prof. X."

The problem is that I am currently working on my MSc thesis so he "is" supervising me now but he "was" also supervising my on my BSc. How can I rephrase this appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> I have been supervised by Prof. X on both my BSc and MSc theses.

The fact that you are *still* being supervised by him on your MSc doesn't invalidate the statement.

---

Alternatively, you could change it to this:

> Both my BSc and MSc theses, as supervised by Prof. X.

But that would likely require that the surrounding text also be rephrased. So, the first revision is simpler.